# Unable to install CPUSim in Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, javafx

I need to run CPUSim Version 4 for a project in my university. Upon following the directions given by the website and the `README.md` , I receive this error:

```
java -cp .:richtextfx-fat-0.6.10.jar:reactfx-2.0-MR.jar -jar CPUSim-4.0.11.jar
```

This gave me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:800)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:698)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:621)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        at cpusim.Main.main(Main.java:73)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.application.Application
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 10 more
```

I've browsed forums and tried to install openjfx but it didn't work.
I tried to download the JavaFX runtime and run it using this command:
`java --module-path $JFX --add-modules javafx.controls -cp  .:richtextfx-fat-0.6.10.jar:reactfx-2.0-MR.jar -jar CPUSim-4.0.11.jar` 
which resulted in this:

```
Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/fxml/Initializable
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:800)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:698)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:621)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        at cpusim.GUIMain.start(GUIMain.java:50)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:277)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.fxml.Initializable
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 19 more
```

Now I'm clueless as to what to do, I'm just trying to get this to run. None of this makes sense to me at the moment. Any help will be appreciated.

my java version:

```
openjdk 11.0.8 2020-07-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.8+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.fxml.Initializable

Basically tells you: the javax stuff is missing.

Thing is: getting javafx to work on some Linux distribution is actually tricky, as there are so many different ways the distributions/JDK packages "deliver" JavaFX.

I suggest you turn to [here](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) to find out what exactly your environment needs.

Comment: Exactly, I am just following that very site. I'm really not sure how to port it, because --add-modules really doesn't seem to work :'( .
I've even tried to build from source, but they use gradle. I'm very new to these so that just fried my brain completely.

Comment: You can just  `apt install openjfx` it worked for me in ubuntu 16 but not in 20

Answer (score 0):

It appears from the stack trace that you are using FXML for your application. The `javafx.fxml` package is in a separate module (with the same name as the package) to the controls, so you also need to include that on the command line:

```
java --module-path $JFX --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -cp  .:richtextfx-fat-0.6.10.jar:reactfx-2.0-MR.jar -jar CPUSim-4.0.11.jar
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it kept spewing out more errors after that. I'm assuming they are expecting me to download Oracle Java 8